# Javascript comma syntax, and complex expressions, minified, obfuscated: please help me understand a piece of code

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

I need to understand some pieces of code. I feel fine with the syntax of Java, C++, PHP, but JavaScript syntax is still a "dark forest" for me. Here are the original forms and possible interpretations, I mean equivalents in terms of program logic:

1.

```js
   var o,
   a,
   s = "https://widget.kiwitaxi.com",
   c = e.createElement("iframe"),
   l = e.getElementById(r.target),
   p = r && r.height_bias ? 4 + r.height_bias : 4,
   u = !1,
   f = parseInt(r.min_height, 10) 
           ? parseInt(r.min_height, 10) 
           : r.hide_form_extras && !r.default_form_title 
               ? 304 
               : 386;
```

I'm almost sure about this one, here I can replace commas with semicolons and add `var` statement to the beginning of each line, and it will produce the same results, am I right?

```
var o;
var a;
var s = "https://widget.kiwitaxi.com";
var c = e.createElement("iframe");
var l = e.getElementById(r.target);
var p = r && r.height_bias ? 4 + r.height_bias : 4;
var u = !1;
var f = parseInt(r.min_height, 10) 
            ? parseInt(r.min_height, 10) 
            : r.hide_form_extras && !r.default_form_title 
                ? 304 
                : 386;
```

2. And this one is really tough for me, I cannot presume any interpretation.

   ```
   o = s + "/w",
   "en" == r.language && (o += "-" + r.language.toString().toLowerCase()),
   ("biletik" == r.theme || "ostrovok" == r.theme) &&
   (o += "-" + r.theme.toString().toLowerCase()),
   o += ".html",
   r.banner_id || (r.banner_id = "22995c4e");
   ```

   As I understand:

   1. "`o`" is evaluated to `s + "/w"`, then is concatenated with `"-"`, and then with `".html"`? Are any conditions applied to that string building, I mean, can any of that two concatenations be applied by condition in this code?
   2. What does comparison `==` operator do in the statement (the part `"en" == r.language...`), which variable receives that result? Or can it be just an obfuscation trick?
   3. And the last one, after the last comma, `r.banner_id || (r.banner_id = "22995c4e");` Here goes an assignment, that is clear, but what is the point of other stuff in this part? Is the assignment made by condition here (`if r.banner is not undefined-or-null-or-false`)?

Comment: Have you tried de-ob the js? http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Sorry for possibly badly formed english, it is not my native language. But I doing the best to practice and learn :-)

Comment: No, didn't ever have a guess that such tools exist. Thank you for the tip, I'll try it tomorrow, I must go now, I'm sorry, we got 8.54 PM now, and I'm still in the office and afraid that the busses to home will end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"en" == r.language && (o += "-" + r.language.toString().toLowerCase()),
```

Ooh...that line's tricky.

So, example: If you were to write `var myVar = false && thisFunctionThrowsError()`, where the function would throw an exception if it were called, that would actually *not* return an error - because anything after the ampersand won't be evaluated. It's called short-circuit evaluation. In this case, someone has cut out the part where he checks the result of the `&&` comparison, and only uses it to determine whether or not to run the right side.

So, if I write:

```
"biletik" == r.theme && (o += "-");
```

That means it will add a dash to `o` only if `r.theme == 'biletik'`.

The last line is the opposite; it looks like it's a lazy-initializer. If `r.banner_id` is null, that evaluates to false - so it runs the second part of the `||`, initializing it to `22995c4e`.

Comment: That is greatly clarifying! So, it uses common for many languages feature: not to continue evaluating the condition and give the result right away, if that result can not change any further according to boolean logic. I understand now, thank you! Now I can go do much homework about this :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot vote up the answer, my repo is insufficient, actually it's my first question on the whole StackExchange. Great service and community with very productive rules, and why didn't I ask my own questions before... Gonna fix it :-)

Comment: Even when you're a new user, you can mark an answer as accepted (if you were the one to create it); should appear as a transparent clickable checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Done. I should go learn more meta after finishing urgent tasks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've written out your second code block in a more "traditional" (non-minified) way. [Katana314's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357107/) provides excellent explanation for how it works and why.

Here's a line-by-line comparison of the original minified code and what I've expanded it to:

###### Line 1

> ###### Minified and Expanded (the same):
>
> ```
> o = s + "/w";     // minified ends with comma instead of semicolon
> ```

###### Line 2

> ###### Minified:
>
> ```
> "en" == r.language && (o += "-" + r.language.toString().toLowerCase()),
> ```
>
> ###### Expanded:
>
> ```
> if (r.language == "en") {
>     o += "-" + r.language.toString().toLowerCase();
> }
> ```

###### Line 3 and 4

> ###### Minified:
>
> ```
> ("biletik" == r.theme || "ostrovok" == r.theme) &&
> (o += "-" + r.theme.toString().toLowerCase()),
> ```
>
> ###### Expanded:
>
> ```
> if (r.theme == "biletik" || r.theme == "ostrovok" ) {
>     o += "-" + r.theme.toString().toLowerCase();
> }
> ```

###### Line 5

> ###### Minified and Expanded (the same):
>
> ```
> o += ".html";     // minified ends with comma instead of semicolon
> ```

###### Line 6

> ###### Minified:
>
> ```
> r.banner_id || (r.banner_id = "22995c4e");
> ```
>
> ###### Expanded:
>
> ```
> if (!r.banner_id) {
>     r.banner_id = "22995c4e";
> }
> ```

And here is the expanded code all together, with comments tracking the value of `o` as it goes through the different steps.

I'm assuming the two code blocks are related, so I used the value of `s` from your first code block in the explanation.

```
// o = "https://widget.kiwitaxi.com" + "/w"
o = s + "/w";

if (r.language == "en") {
    // o += "-en"
    o += "-" + r.language.toString().toLowerCase();
}

if (r.theme == "biletik" || r.theme == "ostrovok" ) {
    // o += "-biletik"  or
    // o += "-ostrovok"
    o += "-" + r.theme.toString().toLowerCase();
}

o += ".html";

// if r.banner_id has not yet been set, set it now
if (!r.banner_id) {
    r.banner_id = "22995c4e";
}
```

So depending on language and theme, `o` could have the following values:

1. `"https://widget.kiwitaxi.com/w.html"`             - when no language and no theme (or any language other than "en" and any theme other than "biletic" or "ostrovok") apply.
2. `"https://widget.kiwitaxi.com/w-en.html"`          - when the language is set to "en" but no theme applies.
3. `"https://widget.kiwitaxi.com/w-biletik.html"`, and
4. `"https://widget.kiwitaxi.com/w-ostrovok.html"`    - when no language applies but a theme is set.
5. `"https://widget.kiwitaxi.com/w-en-biletik.html"`, and
6. `"https://widget.kiwitaxi.com/w-en-ostrovok.html"` - when the language is set to "en" and one of the two themes applies.