# Javascript unusual FOR loop. Please, confirm that my interpretation is correct

Tags: javascript, syntax, minify

I have a piece of code in javascript:

```
for (
    m = a[1],
        s = a[2],
        c.hash_match = i.replace(m, ""),
        o.lastIndex = 0;
    a = o.exec(s);
) {
    e[a[1]] && (c[e[a[1]]] = c[e[a[1]]] || decodeURIComponent(a[2]));
}
```

And how i think is works:

```
m = a[1];
s = a[2];
c.hash_match = i.replace(m, "");
o.lastIndex = 0;
while(a = o.exec(s))
{
    if(e[a[1]])
    {
        if(!c[e[a[1]]])
        {
            c[e[a[1]]] = decodeURIComponent(a[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand, the four operators going before the first semicolon in the for loop can be put outside, because the for loop doesn't make use of the result returned by this comma-separated list of assignments.

The for loop breaks when o.exec(s) is false as of the definition of == operator (not ===).

And the inner code construction have been explained to me in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356907), I'm pretty sure about it, but please, confirm this part too.

I have made some tests and checked some behaviours, but need to be sure that my interpretation is 100% correct, because it's a part of a large js script, and I'm not sure that my testing work would be sufficient to preserve code logic after refactoring. So, are that two snippets equal?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see these two are equal. For clarification: `a = o.exec(s)` assigns `o.exec(s)` to `a` and uses the result (truthiness) of `o.exec(s)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I can see is that

```
c[e[a[1]]] = c[e[a[1]]] || decodeURIComponent(a[2])
```

is more like

```
var temp = c[e[a[1]]];
if(!temp)
{
    c[e[a[1]]] = decodeURIComponent(a[2]);
} else {
    c[e[a[1]]] = temp;
}
```

The apparently-redundant self-assignment `c[e[a[1]]] = c[e[a[1]]]` is relevant if `c[e[a[1]]] = c[e[a[1]]]` is defined by an accessor property with a setter function. The assignment operation would invoke the setter.

In the event that there are no accessor properties in use on `c`, then the two pieces of code are equivalent.

Comment: Oh, that is how it is! Actually I didn't even guess, that javascript does have a possibility to manage custom getters and setters of object properties, similar to, say, C# (of course, considering javascript language differences). / specifics. [defineProperty docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) have helped me with the details (perhaps will help anyone else). Considering side-effects from getters/setters and execution precedence/conditionality, your code looks 100% equivalent. Thank you!

Comment: Can I get clarification on one more thing: does defineProperty have any alternate, short syntax? I didn't find any in the doc, but need to be sure, to avoid missing it, while analysing the code.

Answer (score 0):

And here goes one more. Sorry, I wasn't sure where to place this. This could be a separate question perhaps, but I'm not sure. So, here is the code:

```
function i(e,t) {
    var h = y.map;
    var m = h && h["*"] || {};
}
```

So, considering all know for now, the replacement for function body can be:

```
var h = y.map;
var m;
var temp;
if(h)
{
    temp = h["*"];
    if(temp)
    {
        m = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        m = {};
    }
}
else
{
    m = {};
}
```

And I also can say:

```
var h = y.map;
var m = {};
if(h && h["*"])
{
    m = h["*"];
}
```

but h and m could be defined somewhere else in upper scope and have a custom getters/setters with some side-effects. So if there were no var before them, inside the function body, that make them local, than side-effects from custom getters/setters will be applied to the context twice instead of once, apparently breaking the logic. Is it really so?